# Is 'About My Father' in the 'Meet the Parents' film series?

Tags: meet-the-parents-series

The French titles for the *Meet the Parents* film series are:

- *Mon beau-père et moi* (Meet the Parents). [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0212338/).
- *Mon beau-père, mes parents et moi* (Meet the Fockers). [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290002/).
- *Mon beau-père et nous* (Little Fockers). [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0970866/).

While *Mon père et moi* (About My Father). [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8373206/), stars Robert de Niro and has a similar French name to the other movies, I'm fairly certain that it is not in the series.

Can you confirm that?

Comment: They have nothing to do with each other, a simple wikipedia search would have been enough,,,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not in the *Meet the Parents* film series. [As per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_My_Father), it is

> loosely based on [actor Sebastian Maniscalco]'s life and his relationship with his father, played by Robert De Niro.

The only similarities, as you've noted, are the French title and the presence of De Niro as a father figure.

To explain why this may be the case, there is a known phenomenon - especially with comedy movies - which TV Tropes calls [Translation Matchmaking](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TranslationMatchmaking), in which a film is renamed for a specific market in order to suggest a non-existent connection with a previous film. *Airplane* was extremely prone to this, with subsequent films starring Leslie Nielsen or created by ZAZ often being retitled in foreign countries to make the *Airplane* connection obvious.

I cannot prove it, but my suspicion is that *About My Father*'s French title is an example of this phenomenon, and was chosen to imply a connection with De Niro's earlier film that isn't actually there.